# Can't export class using React JS on VSCode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, export

I can't export default {class}. I can't figure out why. I get this error :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMxOc.png

I have some doubt using the const right here, outside the class, but looks like it won't work when I put it in.

Does anyone sees my error? I am new to React. Be gentle with me.

Thanks in advance.

Here's my code :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef, Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import Nav from './Nav'
import SearchBox from './SearchBox'
import MovieList from './MovieList'
import Pagination from './Pagination'
import MovieInfo from './MovieInfo';
import background from './background';


const Auto = () => {
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState(false);
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");


class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      movies: [],
      totalResults: 0,
      searchTerm: '',
      currentPage: 1,
      currentMovie: null
    }
    this.apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_API
  }


  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ searchTerm: e.target.value })
  }

  logData = () => {
    console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_API);
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${this.apiKey}&query=${this.state.searchTerm}&language=en-US&page=${this.state.currentPage}`)
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ movies: [...data.results], totalResults: data.total_results })
      })

    e.preventDefault()
  }

  nextPage = (pageNumber) => {
    fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${this.apiKey}&query=${this.state.searchTerm}&language=en-US&page=${pageNumber}`)
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ movies: [...data.results], totalResults: data.total_results, currentPage: pageNumber })
      })
  }

  viewMovieInfo = (id) => {
    let filteredMovie;
    this.state.movies.forEach((movie, i) => {
      if (movie.id == id) {
        filteredMovie = movie
      }
    })

    this.setState({ currentMovie: filteredMovie })
  }


  useEffect = () => {
    const films = [];
    const promises = new Array(20)
      .fill()
      .map((v, i) => fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${this.apiKey}&query=${this.state.searchTerm}&language=en-US&page=${this.state.pageNumber}`));
    Promise.all(promises).then(filmsArr => {
      return filmsArr.map(res =>
        res.json().then(({ name, sprites: { front_default: sprite } }) => {
          return films.push({ name, sprite })
        })
      );
    });
    setOptions(films);
  };

  closeMovieInfo = () => {
    this.setState({ currentMovie: null })
  }



    render() {
      let numberPages = Math.floor(this.state.totalResults / 20);
      return (
        <div>
          <Nav />

          {this.state.currentMovie == null ? <div><SearchBox handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} handleChange={this.handleChange} /><MovieList viewMovieInfo={this.viewMovieInfo} movies={this.state.movies} /></div> : <MovieInfo closeMovieInfo={this.closeMovieInfo} currentMovie={this.state.currentMovie} />}
          {this.state.totalResults > 20 && this.state.currentMovie == null ? <Pagination pages={numberPages} nextPage={this.nextPage} currentPage={this.state.currentPage} /> : ''}
        </div>
      );
    }
    
  }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are using a useState() hook inside a class component.

> Hooks are functions that let you “hook into” React state and lifecycle features from function components. Hooks don’t work inside classes — they let you use React without classes.

From: [React Docs / Hooks Overview](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#:%7E:text=Hooks%20are%20functions%20that%20let,you%20use%20React%20without%20classes.&text=You%20can%20also%20create%20your,the%20built%2Din%20Hooks%20first.)

I recommend you to decide between using React Functional Components with hooks or Class Components.

Answer (score 0):

What is the `Auto` function supposed to achieve? I'm not extremely familiar with React myself, but it could be a scoping issue seeing how all the logic is inside that function which never gets invoked.